# PHP - Getting date of birth from database, turning it into an age & if the age is above 15 echo their email from database

Tags: php, foreach

I have a school project that I am working on. I have to get every users date of birth from a database table, then calculate every users age. Then, if their age is above 15, then I need to echo out their email.

When I run this code it just keeps saying Array, instead of the users email. I know it's because I did not foreach the $email_array, but I dont know how to do this in the same foreach as the age.

I have been researching combining foreach arrays, but cant seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Below is my code so far:

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   include('phpcodes/connection.php');

   $import="SELECT * FROM table";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$import);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $emaillist .= $row['email'] . ",";
      $doblist .= $row['dob'] . ",";
   }

   $dob_array = explode(",",$doblist);
   $email_array = explode(",",$emaillist);
   foreach($dob_array as $ages) {
      $today = date("d-m-Y");
      $diff = date_diff(date_create($ages), date_create($today));
      $age = $diff->format('%y');

      if ($age > '15') {
          echo $email_array;
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, when I run this code it just keeps saying Array, instead of the users email. I know it's because I did not foreach the $email_array, but I dont know how to do this in the same foreach as the age.

Comment: The way you structure your code is sub-optimal for the task that you are doing. Rather than creating a string of dates and emails, then turning it into array and iterating through it, you can simply do ``while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){if(**compare dates**) echo row['email'];}`` ... ps. Answering homework questions on SO is not welcomed, the best we can do is point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over `key` and `value` in an `foreach` loop

```
$arrayAge = [
    13,
    22,
    17
];

$arrayName = [
    'Lisa',
    'Selina',
    'Bianca'
];

foreach ($arrayAge as $key => $age) {
    echo $age . PHP_EOL;
    echo $arrayName[$key];
}
```

If you did your comparation in the `while` loop you won't need the second loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (/* the comparation */) {
        echo $row['email'];
    }
}
```